# why the simple regex about "*" pattern does not work?

Tags: python

the code is following

```
str="baaaacbd"
pattern = re.compile(r"a*")
mat = pattern.search(str)
print mat.group()
```

the output is nothing! it is disturbing! Why?

Comment: Side note: don’t name your variable `str`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, don't use python built-in type names as your variable names. Secondly, `a*` means match 0 or more of character `a` and `re.search()` will return the first occurrence of the pattern which is 0 occurrence. You can use `groups()` to see all the matches:

```
In [34]: pattern = re.compile(r"(a*)")

In [35]: mat = pattern.search(s)

In [36]: print(mat.group())

In [37]: print(mat.groups())
('',)
```

Or use `a+` to match 1 or more character, which in this case is what you want:

```
In [38]: pattern = re.compile(r"a+")

In [39]: mat = pattern.search(s)

In [41]: print(mat.group())
aaaa
```